# Laravel update recently modified table

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to update recently modified table `Shops`, where shop now has `country_id` column related to newly created `Country` table.

I have the `*.txt` file with shops and their country code, so I was trying to use

```
 $shop = Shop::updateOrCreate(
                 ['code' => $shop['shop']],
                ['country_id' => $shop['country'][0]['id']]
         );
```

But it only adds new Shops that doesn't exist, and doesn't update the field `country_id` which is currently `null`.

Any idea how to proceed that?

Field `country` in array is appended like `Country::select('id')->where('code', $shop[0])->get()->toArray()` and when I dump the data it's passed correctly.

Comment: That's invalid code

Comment: brackets was fixed

Comment: Have you added the *country_id* in to the fillable attribute in your Shop model?

Comment: Damn, I forgot. Thanks for reminding me... So please remember, to check all models if they have valid `$fillable` property prepared!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have your columns in your `$fillable` property in the Shop Model

or you can use :

```
protected $guarded    = [];
```